# How to use the previous data in the next calculates?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

In this code I used the ***Thomas algorithm*** to calculate `V(k,i)` and `ni(k,i)`.

Thomas algorithm is based on two steps:

- the first is **the forward elimination** (see first loop (`for i=1:nx`).
- the second is **backward elimination** (see second loop (for
  `i=nx-1:-1:1`).

in the first step I calculate the matrix coefficients and in the second loop I calculate the unknown `V(k,i)`.

my problem is:

- how to calculate coefficient `dp(k,i)` which depends on `ni(k,i)`, but
  `ni(k,i)` is in the last loop?
- maybe the question is how to use data of the previous calculation in
  the next calculation?

`K` is the time iteration.
`i` is the space iteration.

```
python
for k=1:nt  
for i= 1:nx
        
        ap(k,i)= 1;
        bp(k,i)= -2;
        cp(k,i)= 1;
        dp(k,i)= -(dx.^2).*(ni(k,i));

        alphap(k,i)=-cp(k,i)./(bp(k,i) + ap(k,i).*alphap(k,i-1));
        betap(k,i)=(dp(k,i)-ap(k,i).*betap(k,i-1))./(bp(k,i)+ ap(k,i).*alphap(k,i-1));
        
  end

    V(k,nx) = betap(k,nx);
    
    for i=nx-1:-1:1
        
        V(k,i)=alphap(k,i).*V(k,i+1) + betap(k,i);
        Ti1= (V(k,i+1)-V(k,i));
        Ti2= (V(k,i)-V(k,i-1));
    end 


 for i=1:nx
      
        
  ai(k,i)= (Di.*exp(Ti2).*Ti2)./((dx.^2).*(1-exp(Ti2)));
  bi(k,i)= 1/dt-(Di.*(exp(Ti1).*Ti1))./(dx^2);
  ci(k,i)= (Di.*Ti1)./((dx^.2)*(1-exp(Ti1)));
  di(k,i)= (1/dt).*ni(k,i)+Ki.*nn.*ne(k,i);

  alphai(k,i)=-ci(k,i)./(bi(k,i) + ai(k,i).*alphai(k,i-1));
  betai(k,i)=(di(k,i)-ai(k,i).*betai(k,i-1))./(bi(k,i)+ ai(k,i).*alphai(k,i-1));
        
 end
    
    ni(k,nx) = betai(k,nx);
    
   for i=nx-1:-1:1
           ni(k,i)=alphai(k,i).*ni(k,i+1) + betai(k,i);
   end
       


 end
```

Comment: Post the matrix equation you want to solve

Comment: The matrix is tridiagonal:  a(k,i) lower diagonal coefficients, b(k,i) is  the main diagonal coefficients, c(k,i) is the upper diagonal coefficients.